# Compare two files in unix using join

Tags: shell, unix, join, awk

I am working on solaris unix.
I have two files:

```
> cat temp
2
8
6
> cat temp2
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>
```

Now i need all the lines in temp2 which are present in temp:
I came across [this](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html) and tried the below command.

```
> nawk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}($1 in a)' temp temp2
2
6
8
>
```

and this worked perfectly.
Then i also saw the the way to use join [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/using-join-command-in-unix.html)
where in it says(and also the man page) that "By default the join command matches the files on the first fields when we do not specify the field numbers explicitly"
So i thought that if i give `join temp temp2` i will get

```
2
6
8
```

but here is waht i got!

```
> join temp temp2
2
8
>
```

Can anybody tell me why 6 is missing here if by default join matches the first column?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to sort files before running `join` in order to match them.

It can be done using:

```
join <(sort temp) <(sort temp2)
```

And my output is:

```
2
6
8
```

Comment: Well i am getting erro:`> join <(sort temp) <(sort temp2)
Missing name for redirect.`.Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: That is because you are using solaris. You should sort the files before. ie: `sort temp > temp_sorted`; `sort temp2 > temp2_sorted`; `join temp_sorted temp2_sorted`;

Comment: the `<( ... )` construct is called 'process substitution'; it's available in bash, but it's not portable. If you're running a bash shell under solaris, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

[`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) is also an appropriate tool, but it also requires sorted files.

```
comm -12 <(sort temp) <(sort temp2)
```

will work in bash or ksh